# angular $stateprovider not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using angular `$stateProvider` to allow routes throughout my app. I have an `index.html` and I am changing the html content inside using the following...

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
    .state('app.accounts', {
      url: '/accounts',
      templateUrl: 'templates/accounts.html'
    })  
});
```

The first route works, when you open the app `template/menu.html` is put inside `index.html`. The problem occur when I try to change the state.

At the moment, I am implementing an API in my app, what the API does is irrelevant, but on success I want the API to change the state to `app.accounts`, see below...

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {
  $scope.create = function() {
  var linkHandler = Plaid.create({ 
    env: 'tartan',
    clientName: 'Example Project',
    key: 'test_key',
    product: 'connect',
    //On success I want to change the state
    onSuccess: function(token) {
        window.location = '/app/accounts';

    }, 
  });
  linkHandler.open();
  }

});
```

Above, on success, I attempt changing the state, but when `window.location` is called, I get the error...

```
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///app/accounts)
```

I am not sure why I get this error because the first route works fine. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong. That's what the error is saying. It can't find that route.

Try `$window.location.href = "/#/app/accounts";`

Remember to inject `$window` in the controller.

However a better way would be to inject the `$state` service and use it to navigate:

```
$state.go('app.accounts')
```

Comment: ok so I did the `href="#/app/accounts"` and the error is gone, but it redirects me to `app` state (the original state) instead. Do you know why?

Comment: Probably there's something wrong in the route and it's entering to the .otherwise() method on your routes definitions

Comment: However, if you are using $stateProvider, the best approach to make redirections is to use $state.go('app.accounts')

Comment: ok well Ill give you best answer because you pretty much solved it, but I still cant figure out why it is going to the `otherwise`

Comment: Use $state.go instead. As you are using ionic, probbaly the path is different than in the briwser

Comment: I did. Still getting the same issue

Comment: Because your path is wrong defined in the state definition

Comment: Could the error be arising due to the fact that I am using `<ion-nav-view>` in my `index` to display the `accounts.html` and `menu.html`?